# How to test a function that has a requestAnimationFrame in Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a lerp function that will lerp an element based on the mouse wheel delta. My question is how would you go about testing this in jest. Right now I am just using a `setTimeout()` function and setting the delay to 1ms because for some reason `jsdom` in jest runs the animationFrame really fast. But using `setTimeout()` seems wrong and feels like it has the potential to fail. So how would you go about testing this in jest?

Here is a super simple example of the code:

```
function lerp(start: number, end: number, ease: number) {
  return (1 - ease) * start + ease * end
}

class AnimateElement {
  private curr: number
  private delta: number
  private aF: number | null
  element: HTMLElement

  constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
    this.element = element
    this.curr = 0
    this.delta = 0
    this.aF = null

    this.animate = this.animate.bind(this)
    this.onWheel = this.onWheel.bind(this)
    window.addEventListener('wheel', this.onWheel)
  }

  animate() {
    let diff = this.curr - this.delta

    if (Math.abs(diff) < 0.2) {
      if (this.aF) cancelAnimationFrame(this.aF)
      this.aF = null
      this.curr = this.delta
    } else {
      this.curr = lerp(this.curr, this.delta, 0.08)
      this.aF = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
    }

    this.element.style.transform = `translateY(${this.curr}px)`
  }

  onWheel(e: WheelEvent) {
    const { deltaY } = e
    this.delta += deltaY
  
    if (!this.aF) this.aF = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
  }
}

const box = document.querySelector('.box')

const animatedElement = new AnimateElement(box as HTMLElement)
```

And then to test I would do something like the following:

```
const box = createMockElement('div', {}) // mock element creator I made
const animatedElement = new AnimateElement(box)

beforeEach(() => {
  animatedElement.curr = 0
  animatedElement.delta = 0
  animatedElement.aF = null
})

describe('Animate Element', () => {
  it('Should', () => {
    const e = new WheelEvent('wheel', { deltaX: 200, deltaY: 200 })
    animatedElement.onWheel(e)
    
    // this seems to pass no matter what
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(animatedElement.curr).toBe(200)
      expect(animatedElement.delta).toBe(200)
    }, 1)
  })
})
```

This works but I have the following concerns.

1. If there is a long animation time will the setTimeout fire before the animation ends.
2. If I set the setTimeout for a long period then tests will take a long time and also the `beforeEach` will reset the delta and curr values before the next test and it will cause the test to fail.

So I figured I would try to make a promise that resolved when the `curr === delta` but obviously you need to account for that never becoming true so I set up a setInterval to check the curr and delta and see where its at and then after time it will reject but then it basically is the same as using setTimeout.

But no matter what I set the delta to `setTimeout(() => //do tests, 1)` doesn't fail even if I set it to like 2000000. So is using setTimeout a valid way to do this and if not what is the best way to go about writing a test for something like this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having trouble with mocha + mocha-jsdom.